# Как узнать, закрыл ли пользователь страницу броузера

Tags: php, браузер

Всем привет. На одном сайте встретил следующую систему: 
Жмем на ссылку на данном сайте -> Открывается новое окно броузера (именно окно, а не вкладка) (URL другой) -> Если пользователь закрыл окно, происходит действие на первичном сайте.

Поначалу думал, что второй сайт эмулируется внутри первого. Потом проверил - нет, первичный сайт каким-то образом определяет, закрыл ли я окно сайта, на который перешел (что странно, ведь два разных окна и два разных сайта). Вопрос - как такое вообще реализовать?

Answer (score 10):

если почитать документацию, то можно найти такое

```
<body onload="alert('вход в окно');" onunload="alert('выход из окна')">
```

Вписываем правильный запрос и отправляем на сервер. Хотя этот способ и не гарантирует 100% проверки (Например, если с синим экраном упала система).

Второй, более глупый способ - это раз в секунду отпрвлять запрос на сервер "я живой". А основное окно регулярно дергает подобное с запросом статуса. Улучшение споосба - сделать commet запрос.

Думаю, там сделано комбинировано.

Comment: Это возможно реализовать, если у меня нет доступа ко второму сайту? Т.е. это просто левый сайт, и мне нужно узнать, что юзер закрыл на нем окно, имея лишь ссылку, по которой этот юзер перешел на этот сайт.

Comment: Я удалил комментарий про дочерние окна, так как ответ @KoVadim покрыл его, почитайте [здесь](http://www.info-island.narod.ru/webmaster27.htm).

Comment: без доступа к другому сайту? вряд ли. Обычно у подобных сервисов есть взаимная договоренность.

Comment: Но я видел собственными глазами, что такое возможно... Без взаимной договоренности.

Comment: пример в студию. Или это суперсекретный сайт? чувствую, это загрузчик на какой-то из файлопомоек, которые предлагают посмотреть свеженький треш и проплатить смс.

Comment: Так, пойдем другим путем. Данный сайт - интегрирован с соц. сетью (ВК) с помощью их API. Но я не нашел там функций, позволяющих определить закрытие страницы.

Comment: понятно, 007 на досуге js изучает. А кто мешает взять и открыть сорцы страницы и посмотреть, что там есть? Тем более, что все нормальные современные браузре содержат внутри себя полноценный отладчик javascript.

А ВК... я даже там не зарегистрирован.

Answer (score 6):

С помощью **AJAX**. JavaScript реагирует на событие "Закрытие вкладки" и используя AJAX уведомляет об этом сервер.

```
client.html
<script>
window.onunload=function()
{
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "server.php",
     data: {online: 0}
   });
}
</script>

server.php
<?php
  if( $_POST['online'] == '0' )
  {
     //Помечаем пользователя как offline
  }
?>
```

как-то так. ( для AJAX использовал библиотеку jQuery )

Comment: Можно пример? Буду за него премного благодарен.

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать [так](http://jsfiddle.net/DBV6z/1/)

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    document.getElementById('testPopup').onclick = function () {
        var win = window.open('http://javascript.ru');
        var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (win.closed !== false) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                alert('window was closed');
            }
        }, 200);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: похоже на рабочий вариант.

Comment: Такая схема сработает на чужом сайте (на моем будет лишь линк)?

Comment: Действительно работает... Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

в скрипте страницы, которую нужно отслеживать на закрытие, нужно использовать

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 // AJAX запрос к серверу что закладка или браузер закрывается
}
```